# does would in this sentence refer to a past habitual action? ..... if not, what does it mean then?

Tags: modal-verbs, would

State governments fund and conduct primary elections much as they **would** any election.

Comment: No. It means "State governments fund and conduct primary elections similar to how they fund and conduct any election". The comparison here is between primary elections and other kinds of election.

Comment: @BillyKerr I understand, but as we all know the modal verb "would" has many uses in English grammar such as: (referring to habitual actions in the past- conditional sentences - Talking about the future in the past etc .....). which one of these uses does the word "would" in our sentence refer to ?

Comment: If an election of any type were to be held, the state government **would** fund it in the same way.

Comment: @BOLA123 This isn't about the future or the past though, or habits. It's more like a hypothetical/coditional would.  A similar counstruction would be: He does X in the same way as he would do Y (If he were to do it).

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks a lot for answering my question.